# Map large Arrays without browser crashing in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

so the array i'm trying to map contains about 10000 to 25000 of objects, and all the objects are something like below:

```
{
 name:"NewYork",
 code:"NY",
 fullName:"NewYork city",
 id:"2",
}
```

so the way i'm using to map this array is as i map all the other lists, but the problem here is it causes the browser to crash, but i have seen in some other sites, that they easily manage to do the same, without any problem or their browser slowing down, so i was wandering if there is a way to handle this without effecting the performance and the browser crashing, by the way, i map the array like below:

```
this.state.CitiesList.map(item =>
     <li className="option" key={item.code}>
        {item.name}
     </li>
)
```

Comment: Why do you have 25000 objects client side? You need to implement paging where you only show like 100 records at a time and fetch more pages if requested by the user.

Comment: Read about windowing https://blog.logrocket.com/windowing-wars-react-virtualized-vs-react-window/#:~:text=Windowing%20(aka%20virtualizing)%20is%20a,one%20list%20item%20is%20visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with long lists is that react needs to render all the items, which leads to a browser lag.

If you are rendering the entire list, there is a technique called windowing, take a look at [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window). It just render what you see in the viewport. As you scroll it renders other items as well.

Here is a sample of how `react-window` works:
[React Window Example](https://react-window.now.sh/#/examples/list/fixed-size)

```
import { FixedSizeList as List } from 'react-window';
 
const longList = [/* very long list of items */];

const Row = ({ item, index }) => (
  <div>Row {index}</div>
);
 
const Example = () => (
  <List
    height={150}
    itemCount={1000}
    itemSize={35}
    width={300}
  >
    {longList.map((item, index) => <Row item={item} index={index} /> )}
  </List>
);
```

You can also have a pagination functionality which prevents from rendering the whole array.